# Remove multiple entities from collection using foreach()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

I keep getting the "collection was modified" error when trying to run this code

```
var mat = db.Materials
    .Where(m => m.ID == material)
    .First();

var oldCourses = mat.Courses;

foreach (var oldCourse in mat.Courses)
{
    oldCourses.Remove(oldCourse);
}
mat.Courses = oldCourses;
```

and I'm not sure what to do. I'm sure this is a common problem but I can't seem to find any solutions.

Any help or even a link to an answered question would be much appreciated.

Comment: copy ids to in-memory collection and remove items by those ids; solutions with copying entire item collections will work as well

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply enumerate this collection for use as an iterator by using `.ToList()`.

```
foreach (var oldCourse in mat.Courses.ToList())
{
  oldCourses.Remove(oldCourse);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a copy of the list of items to remove:

```
foreach (var oldCourse in mat.Courses.ToList())
{
    oldCourses.Remove(oldCourse);
}
```

Although in this case, I'm not sure why you don't just say `mat.Courses.Clear();`.

Are you trying to do something other than remove all courses from `mat.Courses`? Your code is a little convoluted, and makes me suspect you perhaps are confused about how references to variables work..

Answer (score 2):

When you do `var oldCourses = mat.Courses`, `oldCourses` and `mat.Courses` are pointing to the same reference. So, when you iterate over `mat.Courses` and remove from `oldCourses`, you are modifying the iterator that the `foreach` loop is using. this is the reason of the error you are getting.

In your code, you are removing all the items of the collection, you can use `mat.Courses.Clear()` instead.

If you want to remove only some items, you have to use another list with the courses that you want to remove, iterate over it and do `mat.Courses.Remove(oldCourse)`.